# Mocking Scala void function using Mockito

Tags: scala, mockito, spec2

I found a few answers for this but nothing is working for me.

Trying to mock Apache Shiro Subject interface login method which returns void.

Interface:

```
    void login(AuthenticationToken token) throws AuthenticationException;
```

I have tried :

```
   #1
  val subject = mock[Subject]
  doNothing().when(subject).login(new UsernamePasswordToken())

   #2
  val subject = mock[Subject]
  doNothing().when(subject).login(any[UsernamePasswordToken])

   #3
  when(subject.login(any[UsernamePasswordToken])).thenAnswer(new Answer[Void]() {
      override def answer(invocation: InvocationOnMock): Void = {
       null:Void
      }
```

I keep getting NullPointerException on login. My goal is test around the login method and test some success cases along with some failure cases where this method throws an exception.

Comment: The default behavior in Mockito is to return nothing if you don't "stub" a particular method. That is, have you tried removing the whole `doDonthing()..." line?

Comment: Yea so I did read something similar but leaving that line as mock(subject) was giving me NPE

Comment: Consider the () as [] typing on my phone

Comment: can you reproduce this into a short project? I am pretty sure Mockito is stubbing all methods by default. It shouldn't raise a NPE.

Comment: Will do will also go back and I can post more code from method under test and test exception perhaps I read it wrong

Comment: So you were correct mock[Subject] should have been fine because Mockito is stubbing all methods by default. The issue was higher up with how this projects test framework/utility classes were setup. The subject I was mocking was not the one fed to the request. So the code was using a different instantiated subject which is why it was going into actual implementation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The default behavior in Mockito is to return nothing if you don't "stub" a particular method. No need to force a void() function to `doNothing()` since it's doing nothing by default.